# Remove whole tr once click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove whole `tr` when press button called `press me`. I've already tried to do jQuery code like bellow, but this isn't working at all.

```js
$(".btnRemove").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="invTr" data-productId="100">
    <td>nice title</td>
    <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td><button data-ripple="" type="submit" class="bg-primary-darker btn btn-danger btnRemove">press me</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="invTr" data-productId="100">
    <td>nice title</td>
    <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td><button data-ripple="" type="submit" class="bg-primary-darker btn btn-danger btnRemove">press me</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `closest()` .... `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`. The parent of the button is not the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the parent of the button, but that's the cell it is in. To remove the row, you need to remove the parent of the parent of the button:

```js
$(".btnRemove").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="invTr" data-productId="100">
    <td>nice title1</td>
    <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td><button data-ripple="" type="submit" class="bg-primary-darker btn btn-danger btnRemove">click 1</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="invTr" data-productId="100">
    <td>nice title2</td>
    <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td><button data-ripple="" type="submit" class="bg-primary-darker btn btn-danger btnRemove">click 2</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
$(this).parents("tr").remove();
```

or:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//remove item button action

$( document ).ready(function(){

 $(".btnRemove").on("click", function () {
           if( $(this).parents( "tr" ) ){
              $(this).parents( "tr" ).remove();
           }
 });
  
});
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="invTr" data-productId="100">
            <td>nice tits1</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>
                <button data-ripple="" type="submit" class="bg-primary-darker btn btn-danger btnRemove">press me baby</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="invTr" data-productId="100">
            <td>nice tits2</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>
                <button data-ripple="" type="submit" class="bg-primary-darker btn btn-danger btnRemove">press me baby</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `if( $(this).parents( "tr" ) ` will **always** be truthy even if the element has no `<tr>` ancestor.. No need for the conditional at all